# Develop and deploy App service of type API app in Azure using .net core web application project

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azureservicebus, azure-api-apps

**Requirement** : Create a API app in Azure with OAuth2.0 authorization, which will communicate with Azure Service Bus to push message into Service bus queue based on incoming calls.

**Problem**: I have developed a Azure API app in VSTS and deployed in Azure, configured it using Azure Active Directory to do App registration and used API Management Service to implement OAuth2.0 on my API. When I am trying to communicate my Azure Service Bus to push message using queueclient.SendAsync(message), my message is getting into Service Bus but the SendAsync method does not returns and my code hangs on that line.

Then I searched some posts in google and I found that it is some kind of issue and I need to use .net core type project to overcome the sendasync thread problem. So I developed a .net core web application( template API) and deployed it to Azure  and it is communicating with the bus properly. But the app service deployed in Azure is of type Web app but not API app. So now I cannot use this Web app to be configure under API Management Service for OAuth2.0 as it supports only API app type.

**Query** : 1. Can I use .net core web application to develop my API's and deploy in Azure as API app type. 
  or
2. How to use .NET Framework web application to develop my API which can communicate with Service bus properly without hanging in SendAsync method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no noticeable difference between a Web APP and an API App so the answer is **yes, you can** use .net core web application to develop your API and deploy it as an API App.

I can't answer your Question 2 without seeing your code, maybe you missed an await?

Comment: Thanks martin for your response. For your answer on question 1, when I developed my API using .net core web application project and deployed it in Azure  through Visual Studio, it is getting deployed a Web app type. Can I do any configuration or anything else so that my application gets deployed as an API app. For question 2 I used await for the asyn call, I used the same code as shared in msdn and as I said the code is working from my .net core application but prob happens with .net framework app

Comment: Just create an API App within Azure yourself and select it when you deploy it using Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I was dumb I missed that option. This option should definitely work. Will update once I run the full flow

Comment: Hi, I tried the above soltn. but I was facing problem to add my API's under API management Service. I moved to .net framework project to create my rest api and then invoked the service bus via rest api using sas token. I finally went for option 2 in my question and used service bus rest api to push messages